# filter output of vmstat and iostat

Tags: bash, statistics, ubuntu-12.04, sar, iostat

I am gathering statistics data using iostat and vmstat and am running each one for 10 seconds regularly. However, I don't want to print out the whole output. For iostat I want to only show the number of reads and writes and display them as a column. With vmstat, I just want to show the free, cache and buffer columns. How can I do this? Any filters I use just return this result. 
The systems are ubuntu 12.04 on both desktop terminal and server only version. they are run using vmware player.

```
ms total merged
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
758118 836340 1892
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

Comment: You need to tell us what OS you are using. Output format of `vmstat` and `iostat` are different across different OSes.

Comment: it is in the tags. I am using ubuntu 12.04 on both server version and desktop version

Comment: Okay I see the Ubuntu 12.04 tag. Never mind. (But I would rather see it spelled out in the question body.)

Comment: no problem. edited question to say os now.

Comment: Great. This should be answered by others fairly quickly so I won't devote time to learning the output format on Ubuntu. On comment though: this is the type of job for `awk`.

Comment: i did use awk but can only get %nice etc to print. I only want reads and writes though, do you know how to do this?

Comment: the iostat one I was told is this, but it only prints out %nice etc. `iostat -c $INT $CNT  | awk '/^$/ || (/^avg-cpu:/ && a) {next}; NR>1 {a=1;print}'> ioStressUbuntu_$D.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the output formats are as follows:

```
> iostat -dx sda
Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (hostname obscured)     03/22/2015  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
sda               7.02    30.64    4.48    8.32   174.81   789.29   150.64     0.86   67.48   10.76   98.01   1.06   1.36

> vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0 3728772 969952 614416 29911568    3   13    22    99    1    4 48  5 47  0  0
```

You can do the following for `iostat` (every 10 seconds if you'd like to):

```
device_name=sda # or whatever device name you want
iostat -dx ${device_name} | awk 'NR==4 { print $4 " " $5 }'
```

Example output (`r/s w/s`):

```
4.48 8.32
```

If you need a count greater than 1, do this:

```
iostat -dx ${device_name} ${interval} ${count} | awk 'NR==1 || /^$/ || /^Device:/ {next}; { print $4 " " $5 }'
```

Example output (for `device_name=sda; interval=1; count=5`):

```
10.24 8.88
0.00 0.00
0.00 2.00
0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00
```

And you can do the following for `vmstat` (every 10 seconds if you'd like to):

```
vmstat | awk 'NR==3 {print $4 " " $5 " " $6}'
```

Example output (`free buff cache`):

```
969952 614416 29911568
```

Comment: what do you mean by device name? my username? if i do `iostat -dx 1 10${device_name} | awk 'NR==4 { print $4 " " $5 }'` it still just prints it once. any ideas?

Comment: @paul Device name is, as the name suggest, the name of the device you want to gather stats on. Since you don't know what it is, I assume you only have one device; then it's most likely `sda`. Why it prints once: because you didn't tell me you need a count greater than 1. You said you run it every 10 seconds, so I assumed that you run one count every ten seconds. See updated answer.

Comment: I have formatted it now. why does that tell me that the file does not exist yet it works fine on vmstat?

Comment: ok i have tried it with your edits and it runs but when I write to a file, it tells me the file doesn't exist and it is a fatal error-my code `iostat -dx ${sda} $INT $CNT | awk 'NR==1 || /^$/ || /^Device:/ {next}; { print $4 " " $5 }' > ioStressDebian_$D.log & sleep 5 && stress --io $cores --timeout $seconds_to_run echo "This file will be saved to ioStressDebian_$D.log" sleep 5 cat ioStressDebian_$D.log sleep 10;;` the error `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file ioStressDebian_March.22.log' for reading (No such file or directory)`

Comment: @paul I believe I said something stupid just now. Please ignore that. About your problem: `${sda}` is wrong, just replace it with `sda` for now since I don't want to teach Bash. In addition, please give me a minimal example of how you get the error, with variables replaced with their corresponding values. I don't want to debug this (syntactically wrong) huge mass.

Comment: ok it recognises the file now but when I open the file in excel, using the above syntax, the two columns are in one excel column. How can i have the code so that they will automatically separate into two excel columns?

Comment: @paul CSV, comma separated values. Just use comma instead of space as a delimiter. `awk 'NR==1 || /^$/ || /^Device:/ {next}; { print $4 "," $5 }`. Similarly for `vmstat`.

Comment: Ok the csv has worked for excel. How can I edit it so that the heading reads and writes appear above the two columns on my desktop and server?

Comment: @paul What prevents you from doing `echo "reads,writes" >>LOG_FILE` first?